# Op-Amp Current Flow through inputs

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source

I am trying to troubleshoot a relatively straightforward op-amp circuit where I am running into unusual behavior where current is flowing into or out of the input terminal of my op-amp.

The below section of my circuit is responsible for taking a 0-5V signal and converting it into a 4-20mA 3 wire signal.

The part of my circuit that generates the 0-5V signal appears to be operating correctly, as part of troubleshooting I removed R7 so that I could use my offset circuit as a 0-5V test signal.

My first observation was that I couldn't seem to adjust through the full range of output expected as I wasn't able to adjust to anywhere near 4mA.

The second thing that I noticed was that my input terminals of U2.1 or U2.2 were not being driven to be equal like I would expect, even though some current regulation appears to be happening as there is minimal change in the output current if I change the loading.

As part of troubleshooting I have recorded the voltage of all pins on U2 during three different states.

| Pin | Output Open Circuit (0mA) | Output into 100Ohm & Meter (16.12mA) | Output Into Meter (16.2mA) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 out1 | 11.64V | 0.17V | 1.82V |
| 2 V-1 | 0V | 2.10V | 2.29V |
| 3 V+1 | 0.69V | 2.79V | 2.83V |
| 4 GND | 0V | 0V | 0V |
| 5 V+2 | 10.91V | 0.14V | 2.91V |
| 6 V-2 | 1.079V | 0.11V | 0.95V |
| 7 out2 | 0V | 2.10V | 2.29V |
| 8 Vin | 11.64V | 11.61V | 11.61V |

[image: Circuit Diagram]

I have recreated my circuit at Falstad if it is easier for people to view/edit.

[Falstad Circuit Simulation](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWcMBMcUHYMGZIA4UA2ATmIxAUgpABZsKBTAWjDACgAlcDQ8QqsCjx8qo2lSRiYCNgHNuvFChoKQKBL1FswGFTsXLwxFCPBr4UaOvUgA8gDN7AZwYAXNgCc1hsMbV5hXxMqXHhPcEEQbDRzYWixULg2AHd-QL8hOJjIFLSomJo4fK0dE1YTeNossXIaaBokSShLJABlAEtZADsAQwAbNh7xEMgVGmJeXBVApBYkMHgLFGg8QkIwQgQ8BAWFuAm1FbWUMDoTtZpTwMWc1PHeDZC8PX4oXOxn0w+VTLfU77yhSov1utAOjwoNBeWju4Ne9xAeC0XgRSJAhAwJjRVBoGEW4QRShUGJMROauPxqRJiKo1NOKlBdKh6Pw4GZjNZ+nRmNUjJ5XOpZJy8kJhkJhWaOS8gsMGAQpMMIzC0p5aLwGxpzUSUpAcoqo0RGqmzQWuT13hU5uNoPVkwNts1oKtBoR1u0uhApFJPImIRiEEoonqxEgexuNxUtgArq4AA4xkAAGQA9j0ACZyT1+bDYXheqKfGGGu3TQgqN3YPGIstRA2+2t6SWDFmBV4IZkQmYgObIG60aAIDQnISYbA0E7ECB1QeEZRXENwchhpK2AvQteeh5vVdA4rDDcQHKr6lo6nRMw5JyxPe-Spiez9Fy5MlBIxlPxHi1vr+CQJvZO1uiDLiGQ1AwJATT6lEbBAA)

The measured values above are using an [OPA2172](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2172.pdf?ts=1691035606636) op-amp, I have tried two with virtually identical results, I also through in an OPA2180 that I had floating around which exhibited slightly different but still similar results.

I don't really know where to proceed with troubleshooting, I suspect I am either missing something silly with current flow through ESD diodes or my board layout is causing something to go awry with very large leakage currents as I did have to push spacing more than I would usually like to fit space constraints, relevant section of board layout below.

[image: Section of board layout]

Comment: Very well formulated question. The feedback resistors are quite big and I believe Falstad opamp models are not sophisticated enough to show input capacitance (?).  You may need small caps like 20-100 pF between the inverting inputs and opamp outputs. In this particular circuit, you can try to solder a small SMD cap over both of the 470k resistors

Comment: Was this circuit working previously? Your clearance between the R7 and C2 pads seems extremely small, (was DRC used?).  If you manually removed R7 is there a chance you could have shorted the two pads?

Comment: @Nedd, I know they are, it was a bit of a facepalm moment during assembly, I did run DRC but my DRC rules appear to have been corrupted somehow. I verified originally via microscope that they were not shorted, however the above troubleshooting is with R7 removed which makes the clearance at that end less relevant.

Comment: @tobalt, thanks, I put a fair chunk of time into the question in the hope there would be an epiphany while typing it out. In terms of input capacitance is this in regards to potential oscillation? I can recheck tomorrow but I did briefly probe as I have had issues where an oscillating signal causes the meter to produce bad readings. If there is oscillation it is small scale < 100mV. If I were to hook the scope up tomorrow where would you see the most value in me probing, I have a 4 channel scope with isolated channels.

Comment: @Nedd I didnt answer completely sorry, no this is a new design, that differs slightly from what we have used before as there was less requirement for precision, and more emphasis on space efficiency.

Comment: @Hugoagogo yes, my comment is about possible oscillations. Probing with a scope probe loads the probed point with 10 pF or more of capacitance, so probing can both kill off or induce oscillations, scoping by itself is not reliable. What is reliable is if you watch the DC readings at the same time, if they are stable as you put the probe on/off, then it indeed seems to be not an oscillations issue. The caps I mentioned are nevertheless good practice (to keep at least footprints for) when you use large feedback resistors (larger than ~10 kOhm approx., but greatly varying depending on bandwidth)

Comment: @Tobalt a bit of a delayed response but this did end up being the solution, I have a few scale issues to look at but after adding 100pF capacitors on the back of R4 & R5 things are now much more well behaved, if you wanted to make your comment into an answer some info on how to pick the size I can mark you as accepted.